# Boot Camp partition is on lowest brightness and will not change

Tags: macbook-pro, bootcamp, windows, display

It all started this morning, since I listen to podcasts on YouTube before bed. I barely use my Mac partition, but still update it. I use my Windows partition for most of my stuff.

I went to bed with the screen dimmed all the way down and went to sleep. When I woke up, my computer was shut down but still perfectly fine. I started up Windows and after the "Starting Windows" screen, the screen went black since it is dimmed all the way down and now I can't brighten it back up.

Comment: Are you sure it's simply dimmed all the way down? Is the screen just black, or unlit? Is the backlight very far down, or off completely?

Comment: I remember that it is dimmed all the way down and it stays black but the screen is fine a s I can see other stuff and I dont think its off completely.

Answer (score 2):

Just point a small torch (I used the one in my old mobile phone) to the windows screen where it requires your password to log in and you will see slightly where is the box, click then enter your password and the windows will start then increase the brightness by using <kbd>F2</kbd>.

Worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Go into safe mode, change if so you don't have to "log" into Windows with a password or otherwise when Windows starts, the issue is that the brightness <kbd>F2</kbd> key doesn't work until your logged in and Apple drivers load. If Windows starts, then <kbd>F2</kbd> will work to brighten up screen.

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed the Boot Camp drivers for Windows? These give Windows access to the extra keyboard functions such as the brightness control you need. If you haven't then boot into OS X, go to Boot Camp Assistant in Utilities and it will download and install the specific drivers for your model onto a USB stick for you. Alternatively download them from Apple's support page.

If you restart the Mac does the built-in display remain at its dark setting? If so resetting PRAM will bring the display back to its default brightness. Hold option/alt-cmd-p-r when you hear the startup chime, keep holding until it restarts. Windows may override the brightness setting once booted up but this shouldn't be a problem if you've got the Boot Camp drivers installed.

Comment: Failing that you might just try booting into Safe mode in Windows, reset a couple of display settings and reboot.