# Does anyone know why my bootcamp partition shows up as a folder in Startup Disk?

Tags: bootcamp, high-sierra

So recently I updated my computer to MacOS High Sierra. When I tried to boot up my Windows disk (running Windows 10) using Startup Manager, it wasn't there. I looked in my files, and I still had it. "Ok, so it's a pretty common problem. Easy fix, right?" Then I looked in Startup Disk and saw something REALLY weird. This apparently is not normally the case, but here's what it looked like.
[image: Bootcamp is a folder.]

The fact that Bootcamp showed up as a folder did kind of confuse me, and I haven't been able to find any information about it.

When I boot up into Windows, I see a "No bootable device found" error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your computer appears to have Windows installed to use the BIOS boot method. You can confirm this by following the steps given below.

1. Open a Find application window.
2. Select your Windows boot drive.
3. Press the <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> key combination. This will allow the Finder application to show hidden files and folders.
4. If the `Boot` folder appears, then open this folder. Otherwise, Windows is not using the BIOS boot method.
5. If the `Boot` folder contains a file named `BCD`, then **Windows is probably using the BIOS boot method**. Otherwise, Windows is not using the BIOS boot method.
6. Press the <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> key combination to undo step 3.
7. Close the Finder application window.

If Windows 10 is using the BIOS boot method, then you should use the same accepted solution to the question: ["Bootcamp: no bootable device – insert boot disk and press any key"](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/310763/bootcamp-no-bootable-device-insert-boot-disk-and-press-any-key).

Comment: I followed the instructions for the BIOS boot method. It got rid of the "No bootable device" error but then spat out another error saying "No operating system".

Answer (score 0):

I think Bootcamp showing up as a folder is normal...  Here's a screen grab from my system

[image]

Comment: Not for me. Even though I see it as a folder as well, in Startup Manager it doesn't appear.