# Failed paritiong resizing partition in Mojave via Disk Utility (Planning to add it to Bootcamp)

Tags: hard-drive, bootcamp, disk-utility, partition

(Using Mojave 10.14.1 on MBP Mid-2012)

I was trying to resize my AFPS partition to add it later to my Bootcamp partition (in Windows) but the operation failed. What I did was to use Disk Utility's Partition section and resized my AFPS partition and new the new new partition "newly" and left the computer to work untouched for several hours and got the failed error.

Here is the log:

```
Partitioning disk “APPLE HDD HTS727575A9E362 Media” (disk0)

Running operation 1 of 4: Add “newly” 260 GB by splitting “Macintosh HD” (disk0s2) from 673.95 GB to 413.95 GB…
Aligning shrink delta to 260,000,002,048 bytes and targeting a new physical store size of 413,947,035,648 bytes
Determined the minimum size for the targeted physical store of this APFS Container to be 317,972,783,104 bytes
Resizing APFS Container designated by APFS Container Reference disk1
The specific APFS Physical Store being resized is disk0s2
Verifying storage system
Using live mode.
Performing fsck_apfs -n -x -l -S /dev/disk0s2
Checking the container superblock.
Checking the EFI jumpstart record.
Checking the space manager.
Checking the space manager free queue trees.
Checking the object map.
Checking volume.
Checking the APFS volume superblock.
The volume Macintosh HD was formatted by hfs_convert (945.220.38) and last modified by apfs_kext (945.220.38).
Checking the object map.
Checking the snapshot metadata tree.
Checking the snapshot metadata.
Checking the extent ref tree.
Checking the fsroot tree.
Checking volume.
Checking the APFS volume superblock.
The volume Preboot was formatted by hfs_convert (945.220.38) and last modified by apfs_kext (945.220.38).
Checking the object map.
Checking the snapshot metadata tree.
Checking the snapshot metadata.
Checking the extent ref tree.
Checking the fsroot tree.
Checking volume.
Checking the APFS volume superblock.
The volume Recovery was formatted by diskmanagementd (945.220.38) and last modified by apfs_kext (945.220.38).
Checking the object map.
Checking the snapshot metadata tree.
Checking the snapshot metadata.
Checking the extent ref tree.
Checking the fsroot tree.
Checking volume.
Checking the APFS volume superblock.
The volume VM was formatted by apfs.util (945.220.38) and last modified by apfs_kext (945.220.38).
Checking the object map.
Checking the snapshot metadata tree.
Checking the snapshot metadata.
Checking the extent ref tree.
Checking the fsroot tree.
Verifying allocated space.
Performing deferred repairs.
The volume /dev/disk0s2 appears to be OK.
Storage system check exit code is 0.
Shrinking APFS Physical Store disk0s2 from 673,947,037,696 to 413,947,035,648 bytes
Shrinking APFS data structures
Shrinking partition
Modifying partition map
Initialized /dev/rdisk0s5 as a 242 GB case-insensitive HFS Plus volume with a 24576k journal

Mounting disk
Creating a new empty APFS Container
Unmounting Volumes
Switching disk0s5 to APFS
Creating APFS Container
Created new APFS Container disk4
Preparing to add APFS Volume to APFS Container disk4
Creating APFS Volume
Created new APFS Volume disk4s1
Mounting APFS Volume
Setting volume permissions

Running operation 2 of 4: Erase “newly” (disk4s1)…
Deleting APFS Container with all of its APFS Volumes
Unmounting Volumes
Unmounting Volume “newly” on disk4s1
Deleting Volumes
Deleting Container
Wiping former APFS disks
Switching content types
Name invalid.

Operation failed…
```

EDIT 1:
I see the new partition on Disk Utility and formatted it to FAT but after restart I can't see my Bootcamp in the boot menu to boot into Windows.

Here is the result of my "diskutil list" command:

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *750.2 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk1         413.9 GB   disk0s2
   3:       Microsoft Basic Data newly                   259.9 GB   disk0s3
   4:       Microsoft Basic Data BOOTCAMP                76.0 GB    disk0s4

/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +413.9 GB   disk1
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume Macintosh HD            301.7 GB   disk1s1
   2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 22.3 MB    disk1s2
   3:                APFS Volume Recovery                509.8 MB   disk1s3
   4:                APFS Volume VM                      4.3 GB     disk1s4
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert a drive from the GPT format to the hybrid GPT/MBR format when using High Sierra (macOS 10.13.2)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/308824/how-to-convert-a-drive-from-the-gpt-format-to-the-hybrid-gpt-mbr-format-when-usi). 
This same answer applies to Mojave.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This helped me:
http://nerdr.com/bootcamp-partition-lost-repairing-mac-partitions/

But since I was in Mojave, I had to do a bit extra steps to be able to unlock SIP.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.