# Can't see newly created parition (and formatted as ExFat or NTFS) in Bootcamp (Windows 7)

Tags: bootcamp, partition, windows, ntfs

I'm trying to resize my Bootcamp partition and finally shrunk my AFPS partition smaller and formatted the new partition to NTFS (and later to ExFAT) in hope to be able to see it in Windows and merge it with Bootcamp (Since I can't do it in macOS due to my Boocamp partition being NTFS) but I can't see it in Windows in any program I try to merge them. I just see Bootcamp partition and one big "Apple" one which in fact should be three.

(I'm Using Mojave)

Thanks

Here is the result of my "diskutil list" command:

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *750.2 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk1         413.9 GB   disk0s2
   3:       Microsoft Basic Data newly                   259.9 GB   disk0s3
   4:       Microsoft Basic Data BOOTCAMP                76.0 GB    disk0s4

/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +413.9 GB   disk1
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume Macintosh HD            301.7 GB   disk1s1
   2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 22.3 MB    disk1s2
   3:                APFS Volume Recovery                509.8 MB   disk1s3
   4:                APFS Volume VM                      4.3 GB     disk1s4
```

Comment: Added to the post.

Comment: /Volumes/BOOTCAMP/Boot/BCD

Comment: You may have confused this question from the other one I posted (and posted an answer to myself).

I can boot into my Bootcamp now I just can't find the extra partition I have created in macOS so I can merge them there.

Comment: How should I do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed paritiong resizing partition in Mojave via Disk Utility (Planning to add it to Bootcamp)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/354433/failed-paritiong-resizing-partition-in-mojave-via-disk-utility-planning-to-add). This question has the same answer as you posted for your previously posted question.