# Installing Windows 11 on Mid-2011 iMac (full install, not Boot Camp) but it BSODs after the Win 11 logo disappears

Tags: display, windows, imac, startup

I kept getting a BSOD in OOBE when I was setting up Win 11 (error: SYSTEM_SERVICE_EXCEPTION).

I've seen people say that it's because of Windows 11 installing Intel display drivers, instead of AMD ones. It's also the same .sys file: `igdkmd64.sys` every BSOD.

I deleted the .sys file, and now when it boots, it'll show the Win 11 icon, then it fades out after a minute or so, then the screen goes black for another minute or so and then it restarts.

I've gone into Safe Mode and opened Device Manager and now it shows the AMD Radeon driver installed but also shows the Intel display driver which I have deleted many times, which it might be using instead of the AMD one, but apart from that I don't why it's doing this when it's not in Safe Mode.

I booted out of Safe Mode, and it let me into the Desktop for 1 minute before BSODing with the same .sys file. It must have reinstalled itself after I deleted it. However, it has just let me back into the Desktop without BSODing but for how long- and it BSODed when in the Desktop.

Alright, in System Information > Display, it shows the IGDKMD64.SYS driver next to `Driver` but also shows Intel(R) HD Graphics! So, was it AMD? Let's have a closer look. Under the first listing (Intel HD Graphics), the second listing (AMD Graphics) shows "Name" - "AMD Radeon HD 6700M Series"?! What's going on?!! I have no clue.

On the Intel listing it says Resolution: Not Available, but on the AMD one it says 2560 x 1440 (1 hertz), which means it is using the AMD one but then switches to the Intel one (when out of Safe Mode) which results in the crash.

I guess my theory below is correct! It shows the Driver for the AMD thing as "ATIKMPAG.SYS". But, even if I delete "IGDKMD64.sys" (for the Intel thing), "IGDKMD64.sys" comes back.

My theory is that it's switching between the AMD Driver and the Intel Driver, which then it crashes.

Comment: A 2011 computer [of any type] is barely qualified for Win 10, let alone 11. Win 11 demands Secure Boot & TPM 2.0 by default, which Mac doesn't have. See https://jensd.be/1429/windows/install-windows-11-on-your-mac-without-parallels-or-bootcamp-assistant for a workaround. Can't provide this as an answer, it's something I've never tried.

Comment: There are no 'real' Windows 10 drivers for that Radeon - AMD Released one last 'might work for a while' driver for all this series of cards in 2015, then a 'hail mary' beta early 2016 which you should avoid. https://www.amd.com/en/support/graphics/amd-radeon-hd/amd-radeon-hd-6000m-series/amd-radeon-hd-6770m [This has been an issue for ordinary Windows users since 2015] The Intel onboard GPU for the Sandy Bridge in those iMacs never had any Win 10 drivers at all. Intel used Win 10 in the same way as AMD, to unceremoniously dump whole categories of older GPUs.

Comment: … I know all this from back in 2015/16 when I was doing cross-platform  online support for a gaming company. ;)

Comment: Hello everyone! I found something interesting that shows Intel and AMD as the graphics driver (I only have one though, which, a live Ubuntu USB, showed it as the AMD one.) So, please read the post again as I included some more details.

Comment: I also hope everyone is aware that I have been constantly editing this post for every discovery I find, so I'm sorry if the title isn't matching the post.

Comment: No worries - I keep seeing the edits, but keep dropping back in myself with new thoughts. I'd have a look at that guide in my first comment - but be aware that your hardware is simply not qualified for Win 10 or 11, so it's always going to need something 'hacky'.

Comment: Alright, yeah I know. I looked at the guide but I'm not sure where the workaround is. Is it under "(Optional) Download Windows drivers for your Mac"? Also, this is for a newer MacBook, but I guess the same might apply. I did delete macOS but my live Ubuntu USB should be able to get them drivers downloaded. Once I plop the folders in, does it just work or do I need to make it see the drivers?

Comment: You have to work it from top to bottom, because it starts with a Win10 installer, then forces a Win11 payload into it. It's not a trivial task - & it still might not work because your computer isn't even minimum spec for Win 10, let alone Win 11. I have no hardware I can test this on, but these are pitfalls I remember from way back in 2015, when Win10 was new.

Comment: Oh wow. Ok. I'll do it then. Thing is, I have no more macOS on the iMac (only on my MacBook which is what I'm typing this on), but I am too lazy at the moment to copy files back and forth. I'm hoping, and I know I keep talking about the live USB but I'm hoping, that I can do this on Ubuntu too.

Comment: I don't know the first thing about Ubuntu, sorry. Can't help at all there.

Comment: Oh! I thought I did it because it let me in the Desktop for like 2 minutes and I went into device manager but it didn't show Intel drivers and then it crashed. Hmmm.

Comment: It didn't show the Intel thing in the Display dropdown in Device Manager*

Comment: The Intel is built into the CPU

Comment: Yea, so why is it showing up in the Device Manager under Display and Processors? Hm. I also got msinfo32 to tell me if the intel display thing was existing, and it only showed the AMD driver! Yay! Or so I thought. I was waiting for the BSOD and there it was. But it had the same intel .sys thingy so I think something else is loading and using it. It does give me ..._THREAD_EXCEPTION so I think it's the CPU. I will try to install the Intel driver detector thingy in Safe Mode.

Comment: @Tetsujin: This did not seem difficult to accomplish. The only catch is I needed to use Apple Software Update to get a newer version of Boot Camp before restarting. Not doing so will result in a BSOD.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have an [iMac (21.5-inch, Mid 2011)](https://everymac.com/systems/apple/imac/specs/imac-core-i5-2.5-21-inch-aluminum-mid-2011-thunderbolt-specs.html) with 16 GB of memory. I have a triple boot of macOS High Sierra, Ubuntu Linux release 22.04 and Windows 10 version 21H1. I decided to reformat the Windows 10 volume and install the current Windows 11 release in this volume. Windows will remain BIOS booting, where as both macOS and Ubuntu will remain EFI booting.

> Note: Some actions given in the following procedure are not actually necessary to install Windows 11 on my Mac. These actions are included for others, who may adapt the procedure to their own particular needs.

### Installation Procedure

> Note: I used a wired Apple keyboard and wired Logitech M110 mouse.

1. **Create an USB flash drive installer:** Using macOS, I [downloaded](https://www.microsoft.com/software-download/windows11) the following ISO file.

   ```
   Win11_22H2_English_x64v1.iso
   ```

   I also used the Boot Camp Assistant to download the Windows Support Software for this Mac. This should be the same as found at [Boot Camp Support Software 5.1.5621](https://support.apple.com/kb/dl1720?locale=en_US). I copied the contents of both downloads to a MBR partitioned, ExFAT formatted USB flash drive, then renamed the file `AutoUnattend.xml` to `NoAutoUnattend.xml`.

   **To copy the contents of the **`Win11_22H2_English_x64v1.iso`** file, you must first open this file with the DiskImageMounter application, then copy the files and folders found in the mounted volume.**

   Below is a Windows 11 File Explorer view of the files and folders in the root folder of this flash drive.

   [image: File Explorer]
2. **Install a clean Windows 11 Pro from the flash drive:** I started by UEFI booting from the USB flash drive. I proceeded with the installation until the window shown below appeared.

   > Note: Reaching this window causes the drivers in the `$WinPEDriver$` folder to be automatically loaded.

   [image]

   Next, I selected the red button with the white X. In the popup, I selected the `OK` button. Next, I selected "Repair your computer", "Troubleshoot" and "Command Prompt", in the order given. This opened a Command Prompt window titled "*Administrator: X:\windows\SYSTEM32\cmd.exe*". In this window, I entered the following commands. You may need to substitute different drive letters and index value.

   ```
   diskpart
   list volume
   select volume c
   format fs=ntfs label=BOOTCAMP quick
   active
   exit
   dism /get-imageinfo /imagefile:d:\sources\install.wim
   dism /apply-image /imagefile:d:\sources\install.wim /index:6 /applydir:c:\
   dism /image:c:\ /add-driver /driver:d:\$WinPEDriver$ /recurse /forceunsigned
   bcdboot c:\windows /s c: /f bios
   bootsect /nt60 c: /mbr
   exit
   ```

   Finally, I selected "Turn off your PC" to shut down the Mac.
3. **Install updates from the internet:** First, I unplugged the ethernet cable from the Mac. From the Mac Startup Manager, I selected BIOS booting of Windows from the internal drive as the default. After booting to Windows 11 on the internal drive, I entered Audit Mode (by pressing the key combination  <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>). I installed the Windows Support Software (Boot Camp Support Software). **When asked, I did not restart the Mac**. Instead, I connected the Mac to the internet and opened the Apple Software Update application. **I updated Apple Software Update before updating any other items.** In my case, I needed to update Apple Software Update twice, then I installed the other updates, which included an update to Boot Camp. Afterwards, I restart the Mac. Finally, I installed all updates (including optional updates) offered by Windows Update. As you can see below, this included an AMD graphic driver update.

   [image: drive updates]
4. **Setup the Mac for the Out-of-Box Experience (OOBE):** From the the System Preparation Tool, select the options as shown below, then select the `OK` button.

   [image: System Preparation Tool]
5. **Finish the installation:** I turned on the Mac and followed the instructions. Among other tasks, this step created my user account.

### Final Configuration

The information below came from the Windows 11 System Information application.

| Item | Value |
| --- | --- |
| OS Name | Microsoft Windows 11 Pro |
| Version | 10.0.22621 Build 22621 |
| System Manufacturer | Apple Inc. |
| System Model | iMac12,1 |
| System Type | x64-based PC |
| System SKU | Unsupported |
| Processor | Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2400S CPU @ 2.50GHz, 2501 Mhz, 4 Core(s), 4 Logical Processor(s) |
| BIOS Version/Date | Apple Inc. 87.0.0.0.0, 6/14/2019 |
| SMBIOS Version | 2.4 |
| BIOS Mode | Legacy |
| Secure Boot State | Unsupported |
| PCR7 Configuration | Binding Not Possible |
| Installed Physical Memory (RAM) | 16.0 GB |
| Total Physical Memory | 16.0 GB |
| Kernel DMA Protection | Off |

The images below show the use of AMD graphics.

[image: Settings]
[image: System Information]
[image: AMD Catalyst Control Center]

> Note: I selected "Enable AMD Video Quality in supported video player applications", as shown below.

[image: Global Video Quality]

### Activation

Windows 10 was activated before installing Windows 11. The result was an automatically activated Windows 11, as shown below. In other words, I upgraded for free.

[image: Activation]

### References

- [Dual Boot Win 7 on MBR with Win 10 on GPT](https://superuser.com/questions/1518366/dual-boot-win-7-on-mbr-with-win-10-on-gpt)
- [How to install Windows 10 into a 2011 iMac without using the Boot Camp Assistant, an optical (DVD) drive or third party tools?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/308743/how-to-install-windows-10-into-a-2011-imac-without-using-the-boot-camp-assistant)
- [Drivers not working on Windows 10 installed (CLI process) on external SSD running on MacBook Air 2018](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/384355/drivers-not-working-on-windows-10-installed-cli-process-on-external-ssd-runnin)
- [Apple iMac 21.5-Inch "Core i5" 2.5 (Mid-2011) Specs](https://everymac.com/systems/apple/imac/specs/imac-core-i5-2.5-21-inch-aluminum-mid-2011-thunderbolt-specs.html)
- [Download Windows 11](https://www.microsoft.com/software-download/windows11)
- [Boot Camp Support Software 5.1.5621](https://support.apple.com/kb/dl1720?locale=en_US)
- [WDF VIOLATION Blue Screen after Upgrading Mac to Windows 10 May 2019 Update (1903) Edition](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/362637/wdf-violation-blue-screen-after-upgrading-mac-to-windows-10-may-2019-update-190)
- [Bootcamp control panel causes BSOD in early 2011 MacBook Pro with Windows 11](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/431583/bootcamp-control-panel-causes-bsod-in-early-2011-macbook-pro-with-windows-11)

Comment: Thank you - I will try this sooner or later as I need to backup some stuff I've made with Ubuntu

Comment: Works flawlessly :)

Comment: @Jayesh:  I updated step 1. I hope this makes the instructions clearer. I did not use the Boot Camp Assistant to create the USB drive contents from the iso file. If you have further questions, you will need to post a new question. In this new question, provide a link to [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/448340/installing-windows-11-on-mid-2011-imac-full-install-not-boot-camp-but-it-bsod) (or [my answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/448340/installing-windows-11-on-mid-2011-imac-full-install-not-boot-camp-but-it-bsod/448734#448734)).