# Bootcamp cannot download Windows Support software

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, bootcamp

I am trying to install Windows 11 on my MacBook Pro (i9 2019) running macOS Monterey. The Boot Camp Assistant stops with an error at the very beginning when it tries to download Windows support software:

```
Can't install the software because it is not currently available from the Software Update server.
```

I tried using wifi and my 4G connection and I received the same error message each time.

Downloading the Windows Support Software from the Action menu worked and I have this software in my Downloads folder. Because of this, I suspect that this is not a network issue.

I was wondering if there is a way to somehow point the Boot Camp assistant to my local copy of Windows Support Software somehow?

Are there any other options to continue from here?

For further information, I am adding the output of diskutil list

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *2.0 TB     disk0
   1:                        EFI ⁨EFI⁩                     314.6 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS ⁨Container disk1⁩         2.0 TB     disk0s2
  
/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +2.0 TB     disk1
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume ⁨Macintosh HD⁩            15.4 GB    disk1s1
   2:              APFS Snapshot ⁨com.apple.os.update-...⁩ 15.4 GB    disk1s1s1
   3:                APFS Volume ⁨Macintosh HD - Data⁩     50.9 GB    disk1s2
   4:                APFS Volume ⁨Preboot⁩                 269.2 MB   disk1s3
   5:                APFS Volume ⁨Recovery⁩                1.1 GB     disk1s4
   6:                APFS Volume ⁨VM⁩                      5.4 GB     disk1s5
  
/dev/disk2 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            CPBA_X64FRE_EN-US_DV9  +5.8 GB     disk2
```

Comment: There is no way to point the Boot Camp assistant to your local copy of Windows Support Software. Since you now have downloaded the Windows Support Software, you could continue without further use of the Boot Camp Assistant.

Comment: I cannot continue because there is no partition created at this time, unfortunately. I am always stuck at downloading the software in the assistant

Comment: I might be able to explain how to install without further use of the Boot Camp Assistant. Add the output from the command `diskutil list` to your question. I have installed the current Windows 11 on a 2018 Mac mini. Should not be much difference.

Comment: That would be great! I updated my question with the output of diskutil

Comment: @davidanderson looks good. thanks for adding it. I made progress. My problem was that I was trying to install Windows 11 ISO - it is not supported at the moment. Downloaded the Win10 and made it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I posted a [question/answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/449530/upgrading-from-windows-10-to-windows-11-for-free) a while back explaining how to upgrade from Windows 10 to Windows 11. This answer modifies the steps to accommodate installing Windows 10 when only macOS is first installed.

> You should install Windows 11 to use the UEFI boot method.

---

Before proceeding you would need to create a partition for Windows 11. The command below would shrink the partition on your Mac used for macOS to 1.2 TB. Since your drive is 2 TB in size, this would create a 800 GB partition for Windows. If you desire difference sizes, then change `1.2T` to the appropriate value.

```
diskutil apfs resizecontainer disk0s2 1.2T exfat BOOTCAMP 0
```

---

After creating a partition for Windows 11, you can proceed with the steps given in [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/449530/upgrading-from-windows-10-to-windows-11-for-free/449531#449531). You should skip step 1 and start with step 2.

> Note: In your case, the table given in step 4 should be replaced with the following.

| Ltr | Label | Fs | Description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| C | BOOTCAMP | exFAT | Volume where Windows 11 is to be installed. |
| D | W11Install | exFAT | Volume on USB flash drive containing the Windows 11 installation files and folders. |

Comment: thanks for posting this relevant and detailed answer.