# TPM 2.0 on a MacBook Pro with Windows

Tags: macbook-pro, windows, bootcamp

I have a 2018/2019 (sometime around there) 15" MacBook Pro, and installed Windows 10 through a USB, making it a solely Windows machine with Bootcamp support software. I'm wondering how I can upgrade to Windows 11 as it requires TPM 2.0. I'm not sure I can create a bootable USB using Rufus as I read somewhere that Bootcamp's support tools affect the installer and otherwise won't work, so I'm not sure where to go from here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Microsoft officially [acknowledges](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/ways-to-install-windows-11-e0edbbfb-cfc5-4011-868b-2ce77ac7c70e) Windows 11 can be installed on computers which do not have a TPM.

So far, I have been able to install Windows 11 on the following Intel Macs:

- 2018 Mac mini
- 2013 iMac
- 2011 iMac
- 2007 iMac (After upgrading to 4 GB of memory)

I used [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/449530/upgrading-from-windows-10-to-windows-11-for-free/449531#449531) to install on the 2011 through 2018 Macs. I have yet to post how I installed on the 2007 iMac, but the steps are based on answers to [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/466739/how-to-install-windows-7-and-beyond-onto-a-mid-2010-mac-mini-with-mac-os-x-sno).

Basically, the GUI which comes with the Windows 11 installation software (`setup.exe`) will block the installation of Windows 11 on Mac computers. Some alternative methods to bypass this are given below.

## Microsoft GUI Installer Method

Use the GUI installer supplied by Microsoft. This will require editing the registry. I have only tested this using a VirtualBox virtual machine to install from the `Win11_23H2_English_x64v2.iso` file downloaded from Microsoft. I pressed the <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> key combination when the display below appeared. This opened a Command Prompt windows where I entered the command `regedit`.

[image: product key]

The registry changes I made are documented in the article "[How To Install Windows 11 On Mac For Free With Boot Camp](https://machow2.com/windows-11-mac-boot-camp/)" and are repeated below.

> ▪  In the Command Prompt Window type: “regedit” to open the Registry Editor in Windows 11.
> In the Registry Editor browse to **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\Setup**. Right click on the Setup folder and select **New > Key**.
> Set a new name called **LabConfig** for the key and right click on it. Select **New > DWORD (32-bit)** and give it the name **BypassTPMCheck**.
> ▪  You must then repeat the above process to bypass the RAM check and Secure Boot check respectively by naming the keys **ByPassRAMCheck** and **BypassSecureBootCheck**.
> ▪  The final step is to double click on these three values you have created and set them to “1”.

The resulting additions are shown below.

[image: results]

Next, close the *Registry Editor* and *Administrator: X:\windows\system32\cmd.exe* windows and proceed with the installation of Windows.

## The Command Line Interface (CLI) Method

Install using the command line interface (CLI) supplied by Microsoft. This involves using the `DISM` command from Microsoft. the procedure in document in this [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/449530/upgrading-from-windows-10-to-windows-11-for-free/449531#449531).

### Creating a USB Bootable Windows 11 Installation Flash Drive.

I suppose you can try using Rufus or Microsoft's media creation tool to aid in creating a Windows 11 install ISO. Note the Microsoft often releases two different versions of the installation software. One has the file `\sources\install.wim` and the other has `\sources\install.esd`. For Windows 10 installations, Apple has always recommended ISOs with `\sources\install.wim`. The Windows 11 equivalent ISO can be downloaded from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/software-download/windows11). Below are the steps for creating a bootable Windows 11 installer flash drive for your Mac. Here, I assume you already have the correct Windows Support Software from Apple.

1. ExFAT format a MBR partitioned flash drive.
2. Copy the files from the mounted Windows installer ISO file to the flash drive. You can download the ISO from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/software-download/windows11).
3. Copy the Windows Support Software to the flash drive. The `BootCamp` and `$WinPEDriver$` folders should appear in the root folder of the flash drive.

## The WinNTSetup Method

Use a third party GUI such as WinNTSetup. I have not determined a way to verify this software can be trusted. So, user beware!

The author of this software is [JFX](https://msfn.org/board/profile/314753-jfx/) who posts on [MSFN](https://msfn.org/). On February 13, 2024, a [post](https://msfn.org/board/topic/149612-winntsetup-v534/?page_id=13) by JFX was edited. Below is a excerpt from this post.

> Current Version: 5.3.4
> Download: [Mega](https://Current%20Version:%205.3.4%20%20%20%20%20Download:%20Mega%20-%20MediaFire) - [MediaFire](https://www.mediafire.com/folder/53um6k2nmhvd5/)

So, I will assume the above links are to official releases of WinNTSetup. Beware, there many websites offering downloads of WinNTSetup versions, where a few files have been either changed or removed. The file names for various versions of WinNTSetup are given below. The current version as of February 2024 is 5.3.4.

| WinNTSetup Version | Mega and MediaFire Filename |
| --- | --- |
| 5.2.5 | `WinNTSetup_v425_Legacy_Supports_32-64Bit_Win_XP_Vista_7_8.x_10.rar` |
| 5.3.2 | `WinNTSetup_v532.rar` |
| 5.3.3 | `WinNTSetup_v533.rar` |
| 5.3.3a | `WinNTSetup_v533a.rar` |
| 5.3.3b | `WinNTSetup_v533b.rar` |
| 5.3.4 | `WinNTSetup_v534.rar` |

The table of the SHA-256 value for each file is given below.

| WinNTSetup Version | SHA-256 Value of `.rar` File |
| --- | --- |
| 4.2.5 | `777d48083e559ef1a57f48ce74bf58ec6b2f64ecd5a62c039e611d2a69a38fc3` |
| 5.3.2 | `4775b789b7df7c4a4d82307695ddd39467b67393edb8b466db8b9e1bd1b6c05e` |
| 5.3.3 | `f3be4aac9741d295c680457ea07705da4e974b984857e8bd7a545b460baf73b0` |
| 5.3.3a | `daaaf975a7eb563da3afee537c091d1a0b80aff402fd2a60a8b9c3a831772b61` |
| 5.3.3b | `e62943cc41d8d61b3e158100165c738bcf4816ffe18329b8ec788246ff386588` |
| 5.3.4 | `4bec7fb6c5e05f8e7d2482120ecb79ca6e4c8aa51f90a877a681a52c756311d0` |

Below is an example of using OS X/macOS to get SHA-256 value.

```
shasum -a 256 WinNTSetup_v534.rar 
4bec7fb6c5e05f8e7d2482120ecb79ca6e4c8aa51f90a877a681a52c756311d0  WinNTSetup_v534.rar
```

I used macOS Catalina to extract the files from `WinNTSetup_v534.rar`. This first required downloading the 7-Zip archive file named `7z2400-mac.tar.xz` from the following source. This file contains 7-Zip for macOS (arm64 / x86-64).

- [7-Zip](https://www.7-zip.org/download.html)

The following commands were used to extract the files.

```
cd ~/Downloads
xattr -dr com.apple.quarantine 7z2400-mac.tar.xz WinNTSetup_v534.rar
mkdir 7zip
tar -xf 7z2400-mac.tar.xz -C 7zip
7zip/7zz x WinNTSetup_v534.rar -oWinNTSetup_v534
```

---

**Steps to Download Windows 10 ADK into WinNTSetup 5.3.4**

> Note: If WinNTSetup 5.3.4 will be used with a 64‑bit bootable Microsoft Windows 10 or 11 installer, then these skips can be skipped.

1. Extract the files from the `.rar` download to a folder named `WinNTSetup_v534` on a machine running Windows. I tested using 64‑bit Windows 10 Pro version 22H2 installed as a VirtualBox guest on a 2013 iMac running macOS Catalina 10.15.7. Since VirtualBox is a free product and Microsoft will allow free installations of Windows 10 for short periods of use, I did not have to make a purchase. Afterwards, I deleted the virtual machine.
2. Open the `WinNTSetup_v534` folder. The contents are shown below.

   [image: folder]

   Right click on the `WinNTSetup_x64` application and select "Troubleshoot compatibility", as shown below.

   [image: select Troubleshoot compatibility]

   Select "Troubleshoot program", as shown below.

   [image: Select Troubleshoot program]

   Select "I don't see my problem listed" followed by the "Next" button, as shown below.

   [image: Select I don't see my problem listed]

   Select "Windows 7" followed by the "Next" button, as shown below.

   [image: Select Windows 7]

   Select "Test the program…", as shown below.

   [image]

   Select the flashing shield on the taskbar, as shown below.

   [image: shield]

   On the "User Account Control" popup, select the "Yes" button, as shown below.

   [image: User Account Control]

   On the "Files required" popup, select the "OK" button, as shown below. If you do not see this popup, then most likely the files have already been downloaded.

   [image: Files required]

   Below is a snapshot taken while the download was taking place. The required files are automatically added to the folder.

   [image: loading files]

   After the files are finished downloading, close the application titled "WinNTSetup 5.3.4", as shown below.

   [image: close application]

   In the "Program Compatibility Troubleshooter" window, select the "Cancel" button, as shown below.

   [image: cancel Program Compatibility Troubleshooter]

   Close the "WinNTSetup_v534" folder. as shown below.

   [image: close folder]
3. Either add the folder to the Microsoft Windows 7, 8, 8.1, 10 or 11 installation media or to separate media. For example, if installing Windows in a virtual machine where the Windows installation media is an ISO file, then the folder should be converted to a separate ISO file. The virtual machine would then need an additional optical drive to hold the virtual DVD represented by this new ISO file.

---

**Steps to Download Windows 10 ADK into WinNTSetup 4.2.5**

The installer application included with recent versions of WinNTSetup is 64‑bit. The last WinNTSetup version, which included both 32‑bit and 64‑bit versions of the installer application, is 4.2.5. During testing, I found this version could be used to install Windows 11 23H2, when booting from Microsoft Windows 7, 8, 8.1 or 10 installation media.

> Note: To use version 4.2.5 with the Microsoft Windows 7, 8 or 8.1 installation media (ISO, flash drive, DVD or other), you will first need to download and install Windows 10 ADK files to the folder extracted from the `.rar` file. For Windows 10 or 11, you can skip these steps. If you skip these steps, then you will be prompted to download while installing Windows. In the case of a Windows 10 installation, you can select the `Cancel` button and proceed with the installation.

1. Extract the files from the `.rar` download to a folder on a machine running Windows. I tested using 64‑bit Windows 10 Pro version 22H2 installed as a VirtualBox guest on a 2013 iMac running macOS Catalina 10.15.7. Since VirtualBox is a free product and Microsoft will allow free installations of Windows 10 for short periods of use, I did not have to make a purchase. Afterwards, I deleted the virtual machine.
2. In the folder, open either the `WinNTSetup_x64.exe` for `WinNTSetup_x86.exe` application. When the following popup appears, select "Yes".

   [image: uac]

   When the following popup appears, select "OK". If interested, more information on the Windows Assessment and Deployment Kit (Windows ADK) can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/get-started/adk-install).

   [image: before download]

   Below is a snapshot taken while the download was taking place. The 32‑bit and 64‑bit required files are automatically added to the folder.

   [image: during download]

   When finished downloading and installing, the main display for the application will appear, as shown below.

   [image: after download]
3. Quit the application.
4. Either add the folder to the Microsoft Windows 7, 8, 8.1 or 10 installation media or to separate media. For example, if installing Windows in a virtual machine where the Windows installation media is an ISO file, then the folder should be converted to a separate ISO file. The virtual machine would then need an additional optical drive to hold the virtual DVD represented by this new ISO file.