# Install Windows 7 on a (17-inch, Late 2011) MacBook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, windows, bootcamp, virtualbox

My goal is to install Windows 7 on my (17-inch, Late 2011) MacBook Pro. The model identifier is `MacBookPro8,3`. The problem is the Windows 7 USB or DVD installer is not being recognized when holding down the <kbd>alt/option</kbd> key at startup.

This is where I am currently stuck:

I have tried to follow David Anderson's guide:
[No bootable device USB 2.0 MacBook Pro mid 2014](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/225387/no-bootable-device-usb-2-0-macbook-pro-mid-2014/225521#225521)

I get an error message when trying to load the bootcamp.vmdk file (step 7) [image]

Comment: @nohillside: I voted to reopen this question because I would like to post an answer explaining how to install Windows 7 on this Mac without using the Boot Camp Assistant. The answers the OP is referencing in the question, comments and chat are legacy in nature with respect to the OP's Mac. This is because the Mac now has the firmware update included with a High Sierra install. The OP can now install Windows 7 without using a DVD or VirtualBox. The procedure is to long to be posted using comments or chat. I need to post an answer instead.

Comment: @DavidAnderson go ahead then!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When unable to install 64 bit Windows 7 by using the Boot Camp Assistant, many Mac users have turned to using VirtualBox or some other virtual machine software to aid in the installation. There are various procedures given here at Ask Different, as well as other websites. However, the use of a virtual machine may not be necessary, if your Intel Mac is a 2014 or older model and has had High Sierra or newer version of macOS installed.

> Note: According to Apple, Windows 7 is suppose to include Service Pack 1 (SP1). Although, some users here a Ask Different have reported success by using Windows 7 without SP1. This answer assumes SP1 is included.

Below are the steps to follow.

1. **Make a partition for Windows 7.**

   Create a partition at the end of the drive where Windows will be installed. Format the partition as ExFAT with the `BOOTCAMP` volume name. Later, the format will be changed to NTFS.

   The table below shows the expected partitions to appear in the output from the `diskutil list` command for `disk0`. If you have a different partition arrangement from the those shown, then you will have to make the appropriate adjustments to this answer.

   **Table: Expected `disk0` Partitions Based on Where macOS Is Installed**

   |  | Legacy Installation | Current Installation |
   | --- | --- | --- |
   | **Typical Drive Type** | HDD | SSD |
   | **Format of macOS Volume** | Mac OS Extended (Journaled) | APFS |
   | **Drive Partitions** | EFI, Apple_HFS or Apple_CoreStorage, Apple_Boot, Microsoft Basic Data | EFI, Apple_APFS, Microsoft Basic Data |
2. **ExFAT format a 16 GB flash drive.**

   If the Disk Utility application is used to erase a drive, then refer to the table below.

   **Table: Choices for Disk Utility Drive Erase***

   | Label | Entry or Selection |
   | --- | --- |
   | Name | WINSTALL |
   | Format | ExFAT |
   | Scheme | Master Boot Record |
3. **Copy files to the flash drive.**

   Use the following sources.

   - Mount a 64 bit Windows 10 ISO file and copy all files from the mounted volume to the flash drive. Here, I used the file `Win10_21H2_English_x64.iso`, which mounts as the volume labeled `CCCOMA_X64FRE_EN-US_DV9`.
   - Mount a 64 bit Windows 7 ISO and copy the file `install.wim` in the `sources` folder of mounted volume to the flash drive.
     Here, I used the file `English_Windows_7_Professional_SP1_W64_X17-59186.iso`, which mounts as the volume labeled `GSP1RMCPRXFRER_EN_DVD`.
   - Copy the Windows Support Software for 64 bit Windows 7 to the flash drive. According to the Apple website [Install Windows 7 on your Mac using Boot Camp](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT205016), the version of the Windows Support Software for installing 64 bit Windows 7 on your Mac is [Boot Camp Support Software 5.1.5621](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1720?locale=en_US). For other users, if a 64 bit version is not available, then try substituting the 32 bit version.
   - Copy the current Windows `gdisk64.exe` file from [GPT fdisk SourceForge project](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gptfdisk/). Currently, this is version 1.0.9 so the `gdisk64.exe` file would exist in the `gdisk-windows-1.0.9.zip` file, which can be downloaded from [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gptfdisk/files/gptfdisk/1.0.9/gdisk-binaries/).
   - Copy the Microsoft Edge Setup. Here, I used the file `MicrosoftEdgeSetup.exe`, which can be downloaded from this [Microsoft website](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/edge). Choose “Download for Windows 7”.
   - Create a folder named `hotfixes` on the flash drive. Goto the [Microsoft Update Catalog](https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Home.aspx) and copy the files given in the following table to this `hotfixes` folder. Each file can be found by searching for the corresponding hotfix.

   **Table: Hotfixes Available from Microsoft Update Catalog**

   | Hotfix | Description | File Name |
   | --- | --- | --- |
   | KB3020369 | April 2015 servicing stack update for x64 Windows 7 | `windows6.1-kb3020369-x64_5393066469758e619f21731fc31ff2d109595445.msu` |
   | KB3125574 | Convenience rollup update for x64 Windows 7 SP1 | `windows6.1-kb3125574-v4-x64_2dafb1d203c8964239af3048b5dd4b1264cd93b9.msu` |
   | KB4474419 | SHA-2 code signing support update for x64 Windows 7: September 23, 2019 | `windows6.1-kb4474419-v3-x64_b5614c6cea5cb4e198717789633dca16308ef79c.msu` |
   | KB4490628 | Servicing stack update for x64 Windows 7 SP1: March 12, 2019 | `windows6.1-kb4490628-x64_d3de52d6987f7c8bdc2c015dca69eac96047c76e.msu` |
   | KB5011649 | Servicing stack update for x64 Windows 7 SP1: March 8, 2022 | `windows6.1-kb5011649-x86_fce83439d6e9707053b0db1a3eb21f5caedd2e7b.msu` |

   When finished, the USB flash drive should appear as follows.

   **Table: Root Folder Contents of USB Flash Drive `WINSTALL` Volume.**

   |  | Folders | Files |
   | --- | --- | --- |
   | **From Windows 10** | `boot`, `efi`, `sources`, `support` | `autorun.inf`, `bootmgr`, `bootmgr.efi`, `setup.exe` |
   | **From Windows 7** |  | `install.wim` |
   | **From Windows Support Software** | `$WinPEDriver$`, `BootCamp` | `AutoUnattend.xml` |
   | **From GPT fdisk** |  | `gdisk64.exe` |
   | **From Microsoft Edge** |  | `MicrosoftEdgeSetup.exe` |
   | **From Microsoft Update Catalog** | `hotfixes` |  |

   Below is an image of the root folder of the `WINSTALL` volume on the USB flash drive.

   [image]
4. **EFI boot from the USB flash drive.**

   When an image similar to the one below appears, press the <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> key combination to open a Command Prompt window.

   [image]
5. **Hybrid partition the disk where Windows 7 is to be installed.**

   Enter the commands below.

   > Note: The command `diskpart` is interactive.

   ```
   diskpart
   list volume
   ```

   View the `Ltr` column for drive letter and `Label` column for volume label. Here I assume letter `C` is the drive letter assigned to the `BOOTCAMP` volume and letter `D` is assigned to the `WINSTALLL` volume. If your lettering is different, then make the appropriate substitutions. Next, enter the command below to get information on the volume assigned to the drive letter `C`.

   ```
   select volume c
   detail volume
   ```

   View the `Disk ###` column to get drive number for the internal drive where Windows is to be installed. Here I assume the number is `0`. If your number is different, then make the appropriate substitutions. Next, format the volume where Windows 7 is to be installed as NTFS, then hybrid partition the disk where Windows 7 is to be installed. Note, the parameter to `gdisk` is `0:`. If your drive number is different, then make the appropriate substitution.

   ```
   format quick label=BOOTCAMP fs=ntfs
   exit
   d:\gdisk64 0:
   ```

   Choose which table below applies to your Mac, then enter the data in the first column.

   **Table: Entries for `gdisk64` When `disk0` has an Apple_HFS or Apple_CoreStorage Partition**

   | User Entry | Type | Comment |
   | --- | --- | --- |
   | `r` | command | Switch to recovery and transformation options menu. |
   | `h` | command | Make hybrid MBR. |
   | `2 3 4` | parameters | GPT partition numbers to be added to the hybrid MBR. |
   | `y` | parameter | Place EFI GPT (0xEE) partition first in MBR? |
   | `af` or `ac` | parameter | MBR hex code for MBR partition #2. Use `af` for Apple_HFS. Use `ac` for Apple_CoreStorage. |
   | `n` | parameter | Set the bootable flag for MBR partition #2? |
   | `ab` | parameter | MBR hex code for MBR partition #3. |
   | `n` | parameter | Set the bootable flag for MBR partition #3? |
   | `07` | parameter | MBR hex code for MBR partition #4. |
   | `y` | parameter | Set the bootable flag for MBR partition #4? |
   | `p` | command | (Optional) Print the partition table. |
   | `o` | command | (Optional) Print protective MBR data. |
   | `w` | command | Write table to disk and exit. |
   | `y` | parameter | OK to proceed with write and exit? |

   **Table: Entries for `gdisk64` When `disk0` Has an Apple_APFS Partition**

   | User Entry | Type | Comment |
   | --- | --- | --- |
   | `r` | command | Switch to recovery and transformation options menu. |
   | `h` | command | Make hybrid MBR. |
   | `2 3` | parameters | GPT partition numbers to be added to the hybrid MBR. |
   | `y` | parameter | Place EFI GPT (0xEE) partition first in MBR? |
   | `ff` | parameter | MBR hex code for MBR partition #2. |
   | `n` | parameter | Set the bootable flag for MBR partition #2? |
   | `07` | parameter | MBR hex code for MBR partition #3. |
   | `y` | parameter | Set the bootable flag for MBR partition #3? |
   | `n` | parameter | Protect more partitions? |
   | `p` | command | (Optional) Print the partition table. |
   | `o` | command | (Optional) Print protective MBR data. |
   | `w` | command | Write table to disk and exit. |
   | `y` | parameter | OK to proceed with write and exit? |
6. **Install Windows 7.**

   Enter the first command below to get the names of the various Windows 7 images available. I chose to install Windows 7 Professional. The second command installs the Windows 7 image to the `BOOTCAMP` volume. If you choose a different image, then make the appropriate name substitution in the second command. Note: This command takes a while to complete.

   ```
   dism /get-imageinfo /imagefile:d:\install.wim
   dism /apply-image /imagefile:d:\install.wim /name:"Windows 7 Professional" /applydir:c:\ /checkintegrity
   ```

   The next command copies drivers to the driver store in the `BOOTCAMP` volume. If one to more drivers can not be added at this time, then one or more error messages will be generated. You can ignore these messages.

   ```
   dism /image:c:\ /add-driver /driver:d:\$WinPEDriver$ /recurse /forceunsigned
   ```
7. **Make Windows 7 bootable.**

   The commands below write out the necessary data to make Windows 7 bootable, then closes the Command Prompt window.

   ```
   bcdboot c:\windows /l en-us /s c: /f bios
   bootsect /nt60 c: /mbr
   exit
   ```

   Select the red box with the white X. In the popup windows, select the `Yes` button to quit. The Mac will restart.
8. **Complete the setup of Windows 7.**

   > Make Windows 7 the default to startup from either the Mac Startup Manager or from the Startup Disk pane of macOS System Preferences.

   Boot the Mac to Windows 7. At this point, an external mouse and/or keyboard may be needed temporarily. Also, the on–screen keyboard can be temporarily substituted for an actual keyboard. To access the on–screen keyboard, select the `Ease of access` button shown in the lower left of the window in the image below.

   [image]

   Follow the instructions on the screen to finish setting up Windows 7.

   > Note: When you reach the screen shown below, select `Ask me later`.

   [image]
9. **Install additional software.**

   Once the setup of Windows 7 is complete, execute the Boot Camp Installer Version 5.1 (Build 5621) by opening the `setup` application in the `BootCamp` folder on the `WINSTALL` volume. This volume resides on the USB flash drive. The Boot Camp Installer will install additional drivers for your Mac's hardware.

   After the Boot Camp Installer has completed and the Mac has restarted, use the Apple Software Update application to get any new software available from Apple. Note the following:

   - You should install any updates to Apple Software Update first before installing other updates available from Apple.
   - You may need to download only, then manually install downloads.
   - You may need to copy any downloads before Apple Software Update deletes the downloads.
   - iTunes appears to be incompatible, so you may want to skip any iTunes updates.

   Install the hoxfixes in the `hoxfixes`  folder on the `WINSTALL` volume. This volume resides on the USB flash drive. Some of these hotfixes are required before installing Microsoft Edge. These hotfixes are also needed to get Windows Update to work. Install the hoxfixes in the following order.

   ```
   windows6.1-kb3020369-x64_5393066469758e619f21731fc31ff2d109595445.msu
   windows6.1-kb3125574-v4-x64_2dafb1d203c8964239af3048b5dd4b1264cd93b9.msu
   windows6.1-kb4474419-v3-x64_b5614c6cea5cb4e198717789633dca16308ef79c.msu
   windows6.1-kb4490628-x64_d3de52d6987f7c8bdc2c015dca69eac96047c76e.msu
   windows6.1-kb5011649-x86_fce83439d6e9707053b0db1a3eb21f5caedd2e7b.msu
   ```

   Install Microsoft Edge by opening the `MicrosoftEdgeSetup` application on the `WINSTALL` volume. This volume resides on the USB flash drive. Afterwards, you may wish to visit the Control Panel to set Microsoft Edge as default. In other words, use Microsoft Edge to open all file types and protocols it can open by default.

   When finish goto the Windows Update screen shown below and choose your settings, then download and install all currently available updates shown.

   [image]

---

### Other References

- [How to Update Windows 7 All at Once with Microsoft’s Convenience Rollup](https://www.howtogeek.com/255435/how-to-update-windows-7-all-at-once-with-microsofts-convenience-rollup/)
- [Download Windows 7 Service Pack 2 (64 bit-32 bit)](https://geekermag.com/download-windows-7-service-pack-2/)
- [Windows 7 KB4534310 (final update) released, download offline installers](https://www.windowslatest.com/2020/01/15/windows-7-kb4534310/)
- [Drivers not working on Windows 10 installed (CLI process) on external SSD running on Macbook](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/384355/drivers-not-working-on-windows-10-installed-cli-process-on-external-ssd-runnin)
- [Dual Boot Win 7 on MBR with Win 10 on GPT](https://superuser.com/questions/1518366/dual-boot-win-7-on-mbr-with-win-10-on-gpt)
- [How to convert a drive from the GPT format to the hybrid GPT/MBR format when using High Sierra (macOS 10.13.2)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/308824/how-to-convert-a-drive-from-the-gpt-format-to-the-hybrid-gpt-mbr-format-when-usi)
- [Add and Remove Drivers to an offline Windows Image](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/add-and-remove-drivers-to-an-offline-windows-image?view=windows-10)
- [How can I tell if a KB or newer has been installed for Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/750543/how-can-i-tell-if-a-kb-or-newer-has-been-installed-for-windows)

Comment: After looking for and trying solutions for nearly a month, this solution WORKED! Thank you so much @DavidAnderson !! 
I needed to install .NET framework version 4 in order for windows update to work, which I found here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=17718

Comment: I have a problem with graphics drivers in Windows 7. It only recognizes the ATI Radeon graphics card but not the internal intel GPU. I ran the complete bootcamp support drivers and I also choose the specific bootcamp support software driver for intel graphics, but the intel gpu does not appear in the device manager at all. In mac osx they both appear and I can choose either of them.

Comment: I am unaware of any Intel Mac models were you can change which graphics Windows uses. Someone else may be aware. You could post this concern as new question. Perhaps, you may need to upgrade to a newer version of Windows. Or, use a different set of drivers from what you currently have. Apple has documented the existence of at least three other Windows Support Software downloads for your MacBookPro8,3 model. Although, the other downloads may not be Windows 7 compatible. I have also seen where new graphics drivers are downloaded and installed from Apple Software Update and/or Windows Update.

Comment: When I installed windows 10 on the machine it recognized the built in intel graphics card but not the radeon graphics card. Now it's the other way around in windows 7. In mac terminal you can switch between the graphics cards, I was wondering if command prompt had a similar option. I will try and search for a solution. Anyway if there is no solution I am happy with the win 7 outcome.

Comment: If you have the disk space, you could install both Windows 7 and Windows 10. When booting Windows, the boot manager included with Windows 10 will allow you to select which Windows to boot.

Comment: If you are satisfied with my answer, you could accept the answer. This will put a green check mark next to my answer. Also, others will know an acceptable answer was posted.

Comment: Will do. Yes the problem is that in windows 10 it runs completely unstable and I get blue screen errors after I install the bootcamp support drivers.

Comment: Does step 5 and 6 also apply to installing windows 10? And how should the partition be formatted? @DavidAnderson

Comment: Step 6 is not applicable when installing win 10, is there equivilant commands?