# Installed windows 10 on macbook pro 8,3 late 2011 17" but I get a radeon graphics card error 43

Tags: macbook-pro, windows, bootcamp

I have installed windows 10 64 bit via bootcamp but I have problems with the bootcamp support 5.1.5769 drivers. I get the error 43 code. Is there a workaround?

Comment: Did you install to EFI or BIOS boot?

Comment: I don't understand your question...

Comment: The 2011 MBPs were notorious for problems with the GPU. Do you know that the hardware works?

Comment: I know. It works in high sierra

Comment: Since you have a 2011 Mac with High Sierra installed and share the same set of Windows Support Software downloads with iMac12,1 identified models, you may want to try using the accepted answer to the question ["How to install Windows 10 into a 2011 iMac without using the Boot Camp Assistant, an optical (DVD) drive or third party tools?"](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/308743/how-to-install-windows-10-into-a-2011-imac-without-using-the-boot-camp-assistant).

Answer (score 1):

Encountering problems using Boot Camp Support Software 5.1.5769 should be expected since this version is not for your Mac. Apple explicitly states this is for an iMac (Retina 5K, 27-inch, Late 2014) and a Mac Mini (Late 2014).

From Apple's point of view, this would be the answer for installing Windows 10 on your Mac.

> Use the Boot Camp Assistant to install Windows 8.1. Your Mac does not support Windows 10.

Of course there is nothing stopping you from using a Windows 10 ISO to upgrade to Windows 10. However, the current release of Windows 10 may not work with your Mac. You may need to try an older release. You can use Rufus to download an older release of Windows 10. Rufus requires Windows, so you will need a machine that has Windows already installed. You should also be able to run Rufus in a Windows virtual machine on your Mac.

Comment: I can't select other windows 10 iso's using rufus? it only has one option. using rufus 3.18.1877

Comment: There are plenty of [links](https://www.google.com/search?q=use+rufus+to+download+older+versions+windows+10&client=safari&source=hp&ei=OWJ7YrPXCNL59APg5pPwDw&iflsig=AJiK0e8AAAAAYntwSUxRRQHJDyyrP6oKgb0BAMojxVHC&ved=0ahUKEwjz15H88tb3AhXSPH0KHWDzBP4Q4dUDCAw&uact=5&oq=use+rufus+to+download+older+versions+windows+10&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyBQghEKABMgUIIRCgATIFCCEQoAEyBQghEKABMgUIIRCrAjoXCAAQ6gIQtAIQigMQtwMQ1AMQ5QIQiwM6FAgAEOoCELQCEIoDELcDEOUCEIsDSgUInE4YA1CxB1ixB2DCUGgCcAB4AIABmgGIAZoBkgEDMC4xmAEAoAECoAEBsAEKuAEC&sclient=gws-wiz) explaining how to get an older Windows 10 ISO using Rufus.

Comment: Thank you @DavidAnderson I will try that. I also tried windows 8.1 but it failed during installation.

Answer (score 0):

I have posted an [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/376915/does-apple-offer-a-page-that-lists-all-versions-of-published-boot-camp-drivers/376921#376921) which provides a method of obtaining the links to all Windows Support Software downloads Apple has documented is for a given Mac. Below is the output from executing the script using your Mac's model identifier.

```
Marlin: davidanderson$ ./GetPkgUrl --clean --legacy --quiet MacBookPro8,3

Matching URL's are listed below.
http://swcdn.apple.com/content/downloads/04/44/041-84708/yq9w47gthzu8e8fqmad6hx0vs15fuk4540/BootCampESD.pkg
http://swcdn.apple.com/content/downloads/45/20/041-85204-A_24VIQ2D28M/3ln1dqstqacwzknssu2fyu3rqhf3y3b94n/BootCampESD.pkg
http://swcdn.apple.com/content/downloads/26/08/041-84821-A_AMCFPC3QDK/4fffs8qgdflw7pn1finqqd40gifh41mvs6/BootCampESD.pkg
http://swcdn.apple.com/content/downloads/57/55/041-84868-A_402D0DFI39/6uz8hhgtd4b87t00mrq0uihiop5ivumsbk/BootCampESD.pkg

Marlin: davidanderson$ ./GetPkgUrl --clean --quiet MacBookPro8,3

Matching URL's are listed below.
http://swcdn.apple.com/content/downloads/04/44/041-84708/yq9w47gthzu8e8fqmad6hx0vs15fuk4540/BootCampESD.pkg
http://swcdn.apple.com/content/downloads/26/08/041-84821-A_AMCFPC3QDK/4fffs8qgdflw7pn1finqqd40gifh41mvs6/BootCampESD.pkg
http://swcdn.apple.com/content/downloads/57/55/041-84868-A_402D0DFI39/6uz8hhgtd4b87t00mrq0uihiop5ivumsbk/BootCampESD.pkg

Marlin: davidanderson$
```

For convenience, below I have provide links to the downloads.

- http://swcdn.apple.com/content/downloads/04/44/041-84708/yq9w47gthzu8e8fqmad6hx0vs15fuk4540/BootCampESD.pkg
- http://swcdn.apple.com/content/downloads/45/20/041-85204-A_24VIQ2D28M/3ln1dqstqacwzknssu2fyu3rqhf3y3b94n/BootCampESD.pkg
- http://swcdn.apple.com/content/downloads/26/08/041-84821-A_AMCFPC3QDK/4fffs8qgdflw7pn1finqqd40gifh41mvs6/BootCampESD.pkg
- http://swcdn.apple.com/content/downloads/57/55/041-84868-A_402D0DFI39/6uz8hhgtd4b87t00mrq0uihiop5ivumsbk/BootCampESD.pkg

One of the downloads should produce the same files as a [Boot Camp Support Software 5.1.5621](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1720?locale=en_US) download. I would also assume a download of the Windows Support Software by using the Boot Camp Assistant should produce the same files as one of the downloads.

I can not provide a way to determine which download is the most current; other than simple inspection. There is also Tim Sutton's [brigadier](https://github.com/timsutton/brigadier) software which picks a download that may or **may not** be the most current. I have never used brigadier, but I though I should mention its existence.

You could adapt this [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/440907/install-windows-7-on-a-17-inch-late-2011-macbook-pro/441335#441335) to install Windows 10. Some differences are noted below.

- You can omit the following files and folders from the USB flash drive.

  |  | Folders | Files |
  | --- | --- | --- |
  | **From Windows 7** |  | `install.wim` |
  | **From Microsoft Edge** |  | `MicrosoftEdgeSetup.exe` |
  | **From Microsoft Update Catalog** | `hotfixes` |  |
- You should substitute the `d:\sources\install.esd` file for the `d:\install.wim` file when entering the commands.
- Do not install any of the hotfixes.
- Do not install Microsoft Edge.

Note, I have not tested to see if there are other differences.