Following instructions to manually install Windows by manually creating Bootcamp partition during start up it doesn’t show up
I’m in the process of putting windows 7 on my late 2009 iMac. I’ve been working on this for a few days now. I couldn’t just use the normal Bootcamp assistant because of hardware issues and ended up having to do a work around untill I found this post
Which exact Windows 7 ISO is required for Boot Camp v6.1.0 on macOS High Sierra? Mid 2010 MBP
I followed all of David’s steps and got to after creating the manual partition using Disk Utility. After that I put in the Windows disc and support, reset the Mac held option and the Bootcamp/windows start up didn’t show up. Only the macOS and a recovery option.
I tried going through Disk Start up but the Bootcamp partition still doesn’t show up. It said something went wrong during the partitioning process but I didn’t see what exactly it was. I’m not sure where to go from here.
Some quick side notes: being this iMac is a late 27in model with a built in disk drive Bootcamp assistant will only work with a physical Windows disk and not an  ISO on a flash drive.
But it being from 2009 the disk drive is kaput so… I got an external disc drive and burned Windows 7 Ultimate with SP1 to the disk. After that I tried to run Bootcamp Assistant again and it wouldn’t recognize the disk at all.
So I decided to follow the instructions in the post. Now, I have a partition and don’t know what to do to fix it. How do I revert my partitioning?

Ah I see well I appreciate you getting back to me on this. There’s another way I saw to download windows completely manually so I will try that. I just didn’t want to spend along time in command prompt haha.

So, can I assume you no longer have a question? I thought you might be asking how to undo what you have done so far. Otherwise, there are other answers posted here at Ask Different for installing Windows 7 without using a DVD.

Actually yes I would like to know how to revert my partitioning please and thank you.

Yes I saw your instructions on how to install windows without DVD or Flash drive. I’m probably going to have to go that route, I was hoping I wouldn’t have to since it’s quite a process. However I’m willing to take the time to do it.

Are you are referring to this answer. I ask because there are other newer answers which are much simpler to implement. Also, that answer does not include how to get updating to work. Also, have you considered installing a newer Windows?

Yes i was referring to that answer. I would appreciate the simpler option. Yes i was planing to update the windows 7 to 10 after install. the only reason i was going with 7 was because bootcamp assistant asked for 7.

Do you have a Windows 7 or Windows 10 Product Key?

No unfortunately I do not.

Probably would be easier to just install Windows 10. You might want to try booting from an ExFAT formatted USB flash drive (using the Master Boot Record scheme) with the files from a mounted 64 bit Windows 10 IS0 copied to it. Some Macs with the firmware upgrade from a High Sierra install are capable of doing this. If successful, then maybe you install Windows 10 by adapting this answer.

ok i got to step 4 on your answer for the "How to convert a drive from the GPT format to the hybrid GPT/MBR format when using High Sierra (macOS 10.13.2)" https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/308824/how-to-convert-a-drive-from-the-gpt-format-to-the-hybrid-gpt-mbr-format-when-usi/308836#308836 question. and after entering
sudo gdisk /dev/disk
i got this
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.10
Problem opening /dev/disk0 for reading! Error is 1. what do i do now?

I guess they what use to continue by using this chat room.

My instructions did not explicitly state the optical drive needs to be internal. I did not feel this was necessary, because the question referred to " a Mid 2010 MacBook Pro (which has an optical drive)". I assumed that the internal optical drive was working. I have now edited my answer and replaced "optical" with "internal optical".
Evidentially, your Mac's internal optical drive does not work and the Mac Startup Manager does not seem to recognize your external optical drive for the purpose of booting. So, although you state you followed my instructions, failure can almost assuredly be attributed to the lack of working internal optical drive.
You can use the Disk Utility to revert the partitioning. Instead of adding a partition, you need to subtract the partition named BOOTCAMP.
Since you never booted from the Windows 7 installer, you probably never used gdisk64.exe. If you did hybrid partition by using gdisk64.exe (or the Mac equivalent gdisk), then the entries to undo this are given in the first column of the table below.



Entry
Type
Comment




x
Command
Goto extra functionality menu


n
Command
Create a new protective MBR


w
Command
Write table to disk and exit


y
Parameter
Do you want to proceed?



