# Fixing "The startup disk cannot be partitioned or restored to a single partition" error on a fresh Mac OS installation

Tags: bootcamp, partition

I've been working on this problem for over 10 hours. First of all, I installed Mojave using the Mojave patcher on an older MacBook (The model number is A1278. It's a 2011 Macbook Pro) I completely erased my disk before installing Mojave. Here is the output of diskutil list:

```
    /dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *1.0 TB     disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:          Apple_CoreStorage Local Disk              999.3 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3

/dev/disk1 (internal, virtual):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                  Apple_HFS Local Disk             +999.0 GB   disk1
                                 Logical Volume on disk0s2
                                 17B0E440-563B-4759-B442-CC8FE78F58DB
                                 Unencrypted
```

and sudo gpt -r show disk0:

```
       start        size  index  contents
           0           1         PMBR
           1           1         Pri GPT header
           2          32         Pri GPT table
          34           6         
          40      409600      1  GPT part - C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B
      409640  1951845952      2  GPT part - 53746F72-6167-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  1952255592     1269536      3  GPT part - 426F6F74-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  1953525128           7         
  1953525135          32         Sec GPT table
  1953525167           1         Sec GPT header
```

Why am I still getting this error when I run boot camp assistant? I've already followed a guide that involved deleting any hidden Microsoft files in the EFI EFI partition. But I don't think it really did anything because as I said, I completely erased this disk before installing Mojave. I'm at a complete loss here, and I'm desperate for help.

EDIT: I know this question has been asked before, but from what I can tell, no one has had this exact problem. On the posts I see involving this problem you can clearly see Microsoft partitions in the diskutil list. I have no visible Microsoft partitions. I performed a clean install. So I'm at a loss for why I keep getting the error.

I used GPARTED to format the SSD and then reinstalled using the macOS Mojave Patcher ( http://dosdude1.com/mojave/#additional_info ), and I still have the same problem. I don't know what else to do.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Did you follow Apple’s erase and install procedure from a specific KB or web page? Sometimes “clean install” means a couple things. Also - Mojave patcher probably needs explanation unless you removed all remnants of that with an erase of the disk. I’d probably remove the edit and just state any more facts - what hardware - SSD / HDD disk, etc. Showing your references online for what guides you follow might be the best way for someone to spot what to suggest.

Comment: Not sure how to reply to the flag, but here's the answer to your questions bmike.

"Did you follow Apple’s erase and install procedure from a specific KB or web page?"

I just used the disk utility on the Mojave patcher usb I made to erase the disk.  And I followed the guide on dosdude1.com to install Mojave. The SSD I'm using is a crucial 1tb SSD.

I'm tempted to perform a complete wipe of the ssd using a third party app like gparted, and then trying to re install Mojave on the SSD.

Comment: Sounds good - you don’t have to edit it. If after a couple days, no one has suggestions - you can revisit if it’s clear or you have some more information.

Comment: I think it would be helpful if you could include the year and/or model identifier of your Mac. At this point, I believe the error message is correct and that you probably will not be able to use the Boot Camp Assistant to install Windows.

Comment: Hi David, I tried replying to your answer on installing Windows without BCA, but I need 50 rep to reply. I'm desperate to figure this out so I thought I'd respond here. Sorry if it's against the rules. I followed the instructions on your answer, but when i tried mv efi nonefi, it said there was no such directory. And when I try to boot from the usb, I have no EFI boot option. I suspect this is because I did not properly convert my drive to gpt/mbr hybrid. But I'm at a loss. Please get back to me if you can.If theres any way I could contact you, that would be great. I would even pay you.

Comment: Well, I finally got past my last problem. And when I tried to run the setup for boot camp, it came up with the all too familiar "This version of boot camp is not supported by this model computer." But I'm certain that my model is included within the list you gave in your answer.

Comment: How did you download the Windows Support Software? Also, can I assume the instructions you are referring to are from [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/308743/how-to-install-windows-10-into-a-2011-imac-without-using-the-boot-camp-assistant/308812#308812)? FYI: if you do not include a @David Anderson somewhere in your comment, then I *may* not be notified that you posted the comment.