# Startup disk doesn't show my windows partition

Tags: macos, bootcamp, partition, ssd, windows

Macbook Pro late 2011 running High Sierra (10.13.6). I have swapped my HDD for an SSD and placed my HDD instead of my optical drive.

I would like to install a Windows 7 partition on my SSD using bootcamp assistant. For that I have booted a windows 7.ISO on a USB (External physical volume), and successfully created a windows partition with bootcamp assist. Now during the restart I had a black screen saying "...no bootable disk found..." even though my usb was plugged in. I forced manually a restart pressing alt, i can only select my os partition.

Now on my start up disk in system preferences I only see Macintosh SSD. How can I get my macbook to force restart on my Windows Partition and read my usb stick?

PS: I downloaded my bootcamp drivers and have them on a separate USB + on my OS desktop

[image: 1]
[image]

[image]

Comment: You could try to run First Aid using disk Utility. I would do it in Recovery mode. Quit Disk Utility, then quit OS X Utilities and select "Choose Startup Disk." See if the Windows partition shows up here.

Comment: First Aid has nothing to do with this @Udhy implied.  *First Aid is meant to fix logical errors in your file system.* Boot Camp requires an ISO because it will create the installer for you.  Apple has a [support article](https://apple.co/386Gh9y) on how to do this and a similar [question has been asked/answered](https://bit.ly/3bagWNW) before.

Answer (score 1):

A previous answer, which will get Windows 7 installed on your Mac, can be found at [Installing Windows 7 or 10 Pro 64 bit without DVD or Flash Drive](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/225387/no-bootable-device-usb-2-0-macbook-pro-mid-2014/225521#225521).

If you have the Windows 7 product key, then you should make sure you have the latest Windows 7 iso download. You can get this from [Download Windows 7 Disc Images (ISO Files)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/381224/startup-disk-doesnt-show-my-windows-partition).

I will point out that the Windows 7 product key can also be used to install Windows 10 for free. The latest Windows 10 can be found at [Download Windows 10 Disc Image (ISO File)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10ISO). Instruction for installing Windows 10 can be found at [How to install Windows 10 into a 2011 iMac without using the Boot Camp Assistant, an optical (DVD) drive or third party tools?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/308743/how-to-install-windows-10-into-a-2011-imac-without-using-the-boot-camp-assistant).

### Addendum

You could also probably install Windows 7 by first booting from a Windows 10 USB installer. This would then require using the CLI to install Windows 7 to an internal drive. The instructions would be similar to [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1518366/dual-boot-win-7-on-mbr-with-win-10-on-gpt/1518417#1518417). If interested, I could include updated instructions.