# Install Windows 7 on macoS High Sierra (MBP Late 2011)

Tags: bootcamp, startup, install, windows

Device: MacBook Pro 8,2 (Late 2011)

Operating System: macOS High Sierra

Security Update: 2020-002

Boot Camp: Version 6.1.0 (6067.60.1)

---

**Context:**

A couple of weeks ago I decided it was time to do a clean install - from scratch - of my macOS High Sierra and Windows 7 operating systems installed on my MacBook, after a year of use. I used this [video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mIPDA.png.) as a guide to install macOS High Sierra:

The installation was correct and without errors, after that I installed the updates from the App Store following the steps of the support website for the installation of Windows 7 from macOS High Sierra with Boot Camp: https://support.apple.com/es-es/HT205016

.

**Issue:**

Following the process above, Boot Camp created the installation drive, the disk was partitioned during the process and when the computer restarted, this error appeared:

> No bootable device -- insert boot disk and press any key

[image]

I have been searching for ways to install Windows 7, without success. Among them:

- Try 5 different USB 2.0 drives (HP, Sandisk, Kingston): Since in a video they think that the problem with this black screen warning is due to USB.
- Install Windows 7 creating the boot from Windows on a PC with the Rufus application and start from the Mac boot screen (without using Boot Camp). It did not work, although if it recognized the usb with Windows 7 it was frozen when clicked, however with the ISO of Windows 10 following the same procedure if it installed correctly, but the version of my MacBook does not have the complete drivers for Windows 10 in addition to which in my opinion is quite slow compared to Windows 7.

[image: ![enter image description here]

I have done the same installation process with BCA to install Windows 8, 8.1 and 10 and have got the same result.

> No bootable device -- insert boot disk and press any key

Comment: Why did you not used a DVD to install Windows 7? This is what Apple says your are suppose to do. Everything you have tried is what you are not suppose to do.

Comment: BTW, the last time I checked, you can use the Windows 7 product key to install Windows 10 for free. You may prefer Windows 7, but at least Windows 10 is current.

Comment: 1) I don't have a Windows 7 DVD, I only have the ISO that my Windows 7 disc was at some time, if I copy the ISO image to a blank DVD should it work? I put should, because because of the quarantine I can not leave the house and I do not have blank disks in my house.

Comment: 2) I managed to install Windows 10 with the latest ISO image downloaded from the Microsoft website (with USB), but the audio drivers did not work, perhaps because of the process, since I did not use bootcamp, but rather the EFI boot. Because Boot camp gave me the same error trying to install Windows 10 "No bootable device ..."

Comment: 1) You can burn the Windows 7 to a DVD or DVD RW. Windows 10 may require DVD DL. However, you have seemed to indicate that using the optical drive is not the preferred option.

Comment: 2) You are suppose to install Windows on your model to BIOS boot. However, most (if not all) 2011 models can not BIOS boot from a USB drive. By upgrading to High Sierra, most (if not all) models can EFI boot Windows 10 from a USB drive. However, Apple probably did not provide drivers compatible with an EFI booting Windows. The sound not working is one way to confirm this.

Comment: I can not post an answer until I know what you want to do. The Apple way is to use a DVD for Windows and a flash drive for the Windows Support Software from Apple. However, you can also install a BIOS booting Windows by using 1 to 2 or no flash drives. You can also install Windows 7 or 10. The choice is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are happy with Windows 10 and want sound then you will have to install to BIOS boot. The instructions for doing so can be found at [Installing Windows 10 without DVD or Third Party Tools](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/308743/how-to-install-windows-10-into-a-2011-imac-without-using-the-boot-camp-assistant/308812#308812). I would recommend first uninstalling the UEFI booting Windows 10 you have already installed. This is not covered in the link given in this answer.

Another possibility would be to convert your existing Windows 10 installation from UEFI to BIOS booting. I have never tried this to fix a driver problem, but this might be worth attempting. The steps would be as follows.

1. From Windows, [download gdisk](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gptfdisk/).
2. Copy `gdisk64.exe` to the Windows 10 flash drive.
3. Boot from the Windows 10 flash drive.
4. Open a Command Prompt window.
5. Use Windows commands to remove the Windows UEFI boot files from EFI partition.
6. Use [gdisk](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/) to convert internal drive to hybrid partitioning.
7. Use Windows commands to install the BIOS boot data and files.
8. Boot back to Windows.
9. Maybe reinstall the Window Support Software.