# Boot Camp Assistant: error while formatting flash drive

Tags: macos, windows, bootcamp, adobe-flash

Hello everyone. A few days I tried to install Windows 10 on my MacBook 13' mid 2010 running OS X Catalina. That was a horrible experience.

First I edited info.plist in Boot Camp's contents, everything worked fine until I started to make flash drive. I've normally chosen flash that I've already formatted(Fat32, master boot record) in Disk Utility and clicked on start. Boot Camp wrote that he is formatting my flash drive and when the progress bar was half full, it shows me error message "An error occurred while formatting flash drive"(this is an approximate translation from Russian).

Than I thought that the problem is out of non-supported OS X and installed maximum supported High Sierra. In this OS I couldn't even start program, it closed immediately after editing info.plist(no commands in command line helped).

Also I tried to install El Capitan, but it also caused a problem: installer is damaged. I read in internet that I just need to change the date on my computer but it didn't work.

Without despair I tried to make flash drive with command line. Most of files were copied except install.wim. It told me "/Volumes/windows10/sources/install.wim file too large". But part of this file was copied so I tried to install Windows. Laptop restarted, white than black screen and shows me a problem: "non-system disk press any key to reboot". I also tried to install windows directly without boot camp, but when windows was installed and Mac was rebooted after installing any software or drivers, it caused me problem with wrong start. And yes, this computer can run windows 10, I've already installed it on my old hdd (I changed HDD on SSD, so I can't access to old HDD).

I don't think that problem is with my flash drive, because I've installed with it Windows 7  on another average computer(We have 2 windows computers in my family) a few days ago. If you can, please help me with this problem

Comment: The latest Windows 10 installers won't fit on a FAT32 drive, because of the 4GB file-size limit. Latest Boot Camp can work from ExFAT drives, which doesn't have this limit. See how it goes with ExFAT. As that Mac isn't supported for either Catalina or Win10, I idk whether you may have just hit a wall...

Comment: Apple designed 2010 Macs to install a BIOS booting Windows. To use the Windows installer GUI, you will have to BIOS boot the installer. However, your Mac may not be able to BIOS boot an ExFAT formatted flash drive Windows 10 installer. If you can EFI boot from the flash drive, then you can try BIOS booting the Window 10 installer from the internal drive. This worked for a 2012 MBP. See this [question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/405144/mid-2012-mbp-bootcamp-installation).

Comment: David, thank you very much!!! Proscess of instalation started an I hope it will work!

Comment: Will Apple fix this bug?  Windows ISOs have been >4GB for >5 years now!  Formatting with ExFAT is great, but, BCA won't install the ISO onto the flash drive, regardless. From what I've seen, any manual attempt will disable BootCamp boot selection as well.

Comment: Ever get this to work?  What steps did you use to force it to work? Been fighting this for a week now and still no joy. Surely someone has a hack!

Comment: @MC9000, yup, everything worked. Got instructions from this  [question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/405144/mid-2012-mbp-bootcamp-installation)

Comment: I actually got a USB drive to boot and begin the installation process (tried 6X now with different versions - all failed), but keep getting the dreaded message "Windows could not prepare the computer to boot into the next phase of installation" message during setup. I've heard it's a driver problem, however, the apple drivers are all unsigned, so Win10 refuses to use them (had those on another USB disk to add drivers for setup). Apple's drivers only work ONCE win10 is actually installed (the part I can never get to).  Perhaps there's unsupported hardware in late 2013 iMac models

Comment: The answer here https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/405144/mid-2012-mbp-bootcamp-installation is ONLY for that particular 2012 model with a hybrid drive.