# Bootcamp - Windows 7 Installation Help

Tags: windows, bootcamp, imac, install

I have a mid 2011 21.5” iMac with High Sierra, the disk drive I think has an issue, it writes to DVDs but can’t read. I successfully burned Windows ISO to a DVD+ disk but the drive reads it as blank DVD, I confirmed this by using another pc.

I went to the USB drive way, I modified the BootCamp plist file to enable USB drive, I successfully created windows installation drive with BC, sat the partition, but when the Mac boots, it goes to a black screen, with a message “no bootable device”. I couldn’t find any way to read from the USB drive, I used both USB 2.0 and 3.0.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You have to install Windows 7 to BIOS boot. EFI booting is not possible for two reasons. First the EFI firmware in your Mac is not new enough. Second, the drivers are for a BIOS booting Windows. The Apple way is to use a the Boot Camp Assistant and a Windows 7 DVD. You can choose either a 32 bit for 64 bit Windows. Windows 7 should include SP1. You can download the current [Windows 7 from Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows7). If necessary, the Window Support Software (Boot Camp Support Software) can be downloaded from the Apple website [Install Windows 7 on your Mac using Boot Camp](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT205016).

> ***Your model Mac can not BIOS boot from a USB port. Therefore, modifying the Boot Camp Assistant application to create a Windows 7 USB installer is a pointless waste of time.***

If the use of a DVD is not an option, then the following methods can be used or adapted.

- The [VM method](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/225387/no-bootable-device-usb-2-0-macbook-pro-mid-2014/225521#225521). Here, a virtual machine is *only* used to install Windows 7.
- The [GUI method](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/405144/mid-2012-mbp-bootcamp-installation/405185#405185). The answer is for Windows 10. You will have to adapt for Windows 7.
- The [CLI method](https://superuser.com/questions/1518366/dual-boot-win-7-on-mbr-with-win-10-on-gpt). The answer is for a Windows 7 and 10 dual boot. You will have to adapt to omit Windows 10.