# Want to put Windows 10 or MacOS on a IMAC with corrupted HHD

Tags: windows, imac

I had an old iMAC with a corrupted HHD, I tried every fix but nothing worked so now Im trying to install windows 10 on it. I tried putting an ssd with windows 10 on it but it just says that there is a problem.

The iMac model is iMac 21.5-Inch "Core i5" 2.5 (Mid-2011) which has 4GB of RAM and 500GB HHD.

I also tried installing macos into the ssd with another mac but when I put the ssd into the IMAC it doesnt detect any disk

Comment: What is the model year of the other Mac? Which version of macOS? I am currently entering this comment from a iMac 21.5-Inch "Core i5" 2.5 (Mid-2011) which has 16 GB of RAM and 500 GB HHD. I have High Sierra (macOS 10.13.6), Windows 10 and Ubuntu Linux installed. I should point out that when installing High Sierra, firmware upgrades are also installed. If you first install High Sierra using a different Mac onto the SSD and transfer the SSD to 2011 iMac, then the firmware upgrades will not occur on the 2011 iMac.

Comment: Do you know which version of macOS was installed on the corrupted HDD? Or, what was the newest version of macOS install on the iMac? Do you have the product key needed to install Windows 10 on the iMac?

Answer (score 1):

You model Mac supports OS X 10.6.6 through macOS 10.13.6. Usually you can download macOS 10.13.6 (High Sierra) using another Mac from [this Apple website](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT211683). You can then create a flash drive installer using the instructions given on [this Apple website](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201372). If this does not work, then other options can be found [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/309399/how-can-i-download-an-older-version-of-os-x-macos).

Officially, your Mac supports 64 bit Windows 7 through Windows 8.1. The easiest way to install Windows 10 is first use the Boot Camp Assistant to first install Windows 7, 8 or 8.1, then upgrade to Windows 10. This requires Windows 7, 8 or 8.1 to exist on a DVD and that the Mac has a working optical drive.

If you try to install Windows manually, then note the following.

- The Boot Camp Assistant will install Windows to BIOS boot. You can try to UEFI boot Windows, but this may lead to driver problems.
- The Windows Support Software for 64 bit installations of Windows 7, 8, 8.1 and 10 for your model Mac can be found at [Boot Camp Support Software 5.1.5621](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1720?locale=en_US). You can also download this software by using the Boot Camp Assistant.
- Many answers have been post here at Ask Different for installing Windows on on Intel Macs. For example, see [How to install Windows 10 into a 2011 iMac without using the Boot Camp Assistant, an optical (DVD) drive or third party tools?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/308743/how-to-install-windows-10-into-a-2011-imac-without-using-the-boot-camp-assistant)