# Diskutil showing multiple Bootcamp disks, how to remove?

Tags: terminal, bootcamp, disk-utility, partition

I have been trying to install Win10 on a legacy bootcamp, but BCA keeps freezing at the partitioning step, running `distil list` gives the following:

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *480.1 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk1         479.9 GB   disk0s2

/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +479.9 GB   disk1
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume MacOS                   31.9 GB    disk1s1
   2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 24.0 MB    disk1s2
   3:                APFS Volume Recovery                507.4 MB   disk1s3
   4:                APFS Volume VM                      1.1 GB     disk1s4

/dev/disk2 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     FDisk_partition_scheme                        *62.0 GB    disk2
   1:               Windows_NTFS WinInstall              62.0 GB    disk2s1

/dev/disk3 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            CCCOMA_X64FRE_EN-US... +5.9 GB     disk3

/dev/disk4 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            Boot Camp              +2.8 GB     disk4

/dev/disk5 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            Boot Camp              +2.8 GB     disk5
```

How do I remove the bottom two disks?

Comment: They're disk images, not real, & nothing to do with your main 'hard drive'. What do you mean by 'legacy bootcamp'? Please describe your method, your Mac & current macOS.

Comment: Sorry, MBP mid-2012 running Mojave, trying to install Win10 using legacy bios (not EFI), created a new fat-32 partition for windows, win10 USB boot drive set as MBR, but Mac boot options only offering EFI boot. Gave up on this method and tried to use BCA instead, but it hangs at the partition step, out of curiosity I looked at the Diskutil and showed me those multiple bootcamp disk images.

Comment: The commands would be `diskutil eject disk4` and `diskutil eject disk5`. BTW, there are two different methods that can be used to install a BIOS booting Windows 10 from a UEFI booting Windows 10 flash drive. One such method is given [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/308743/how-to-install-windows-10-into-a-2011-imac-without-using-the-boot-camp-assistant/308812#308812). This answer would have to be modified slightly to fit your Mac.