# You cannot partition an external disk, a RAID disk or an internal disk on which FileVault encryption is in progress. (I don't have a RAID disk)

Tags: mac, bootcamp, disk-utility, high-sierra, mac-pro

I'm trying to Boot Camp my Mac Pro (2010. High Sierra) And every time i open the Boot Camp it shows me this message: "You cannot partition an external disk, a RAID disk or an internal disk on which FileVault encryption is in progress". Im trying to install windows 10 on my 256 GB SSD (or my 1 TB HDD) using external USB (32GB formated to MS-DOS(FAT))Here's the output of commands: "diskutil list" , "diskutil cs list" and "diskutil info disk0".

```
Studio-2:~ studio2$ diskutil cs list
No CoreStorage logical volume groups found
Studio-2:~ studio2$ diskutil list
/dev/disk0 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *256.1 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk1         255.9 GB   disk0s2

/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +255.9 GB   disk1
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume MacOSX Sierra SSD       54.8 GB    disk1s1
   2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 21.5 MB    disk1s2
   3:                APFS Volume Recovery                515.0 MB   disk1s3
   4:                APFS Volume VM                      20.5 KB    disk1s4

/dev/disk2 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *1.0 TB     disk2
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk2s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Dane                    999.3 GB   disk2s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Boot OS X               650.0 MB   disk2s3

/dev/disk3 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     FDisk_partition_scheme                        *31.5 GB    disk3
   1:                 DOS_FAT_32 WIN                     31.5 GB    disk3s1

/dev/disk4 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            Boot Camp              +1.4 GB     disk4

Studio-2:~ studio2$ diskutil info disk0
   Device Identifier:        disk0
   Device Node:              /dev/disk0
   Whole:                    Yes
   Part of Whole:            disk0
   Device / Media Name:      SAMSUNG MZHPV256HDGL-00000

   Volume Name:              Not applicable (no file system)
   Mounted:                  Not applicable (no file system)
   File System:              None

   Content (IOContent):      GUID_partition_scheme
   OS Can Be Installed:      No
   Media Type:               Generic
   Protocol:                 PCI
   SMART Status:             Verified

   Disk Size:                256.1 GB (256060514304 Bytes) (exactly 500118192 512-Byte-Units)
   Device Block Size:        512 Bytes

   Read-Only Media:          No
   Read-Only Volume:         Not applicable (no file system)

   Device Location:          External
   Removable Media:          Fixed

   Solid State:              Yes
   Virtual:                  No
   Hardware AES Support:     No
```

Can you please help me? I don't know what to do anymore. (File Vault is disabled)

Comment: What version of Boot Camp - wild guess it may be one too old to understand APFS.

Comment: I think its the newest avaible for high sierra. I checked for any updates on app store and it didnt show any.

Comment: You won't find any updates at all on the App Store for High Sierra. It's long out of support. Current support goes back only as far as Catalina - Mojave & earlier are now 'legacy' ie abandoned. Winipedia has a list of what versions match what hardware - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boot_Camp_(software) - note you will probably on a Mac of that age have to install Win7 from DVD then upgrade online. Win10 is not supported on hardware pre-2015 & Microsoft have even dropped support for some newer than that.

Comment: I was able to do a clean install of Windows 20 (21H1) on my 2011 iMac, which also has the current version of High Sierra. I do not think you can use the Boot Camp Assistant to complete the installation. I posted the instructions at "[How to install Windows 10 into a 2011 iMac without using the Boot Camp Assistant, an optical (DVD) drive or third party tools?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/308743/how-to-install-windows-10-into-a-2011-imac-without-using-the-boot-camp-assistant)".

Comment: Thank you David, Im gonna follow the instructions and see if it works for me.