# How to install Windows on MacBook Pro 13" Early 2011

Tags: macbook-pro, windows, bootcamp

Just want to know if it is possible to install Windows on my Mac. My Mac has a 1TB internal and I've only used 78GB. When I try to install using the Boot Camp Assistant, it is still asking for bootable flash drive, but I don't have one. Why is it that videos on YouTube can install Windows without asking for a flash drive?

Comment: What version of Windows are you trying to install? Which macOS is installed on your MBP?

Answer (score 1):

According to [everymac.com](https://everymac.com/systems/by_year/macs-released-in-2011.html), the Boot Camp Assistant can be used to install at least the following versions of Windows. The Apple websites [Install Windows 7 on your Mac using Boot Camp](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT205016) and [Use Windows 8.1 on your Mac with Boot Camp](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201457) can confirm this information.

- Windows 7 Service Pack 1 (32 bit)
- Windows 7 Service Pack 1 (64 bit)
- Windows 8 (64 bit)
- Windows 8.1 (64 bit)

According to the Apple website [Install Windows 10 on your Mac with Boot Camp Assistant](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201468), your Mac is not on the list of Macs that can install Windows 10 by using the Boot Camp Assistant. However, upgrading from a 64 bit Windows installed using the Boot Camp Assistant to a 64 bit Windows 10 is probably possible. If you have (or had) High Sierra installed on your Mac, then instructions for installing Windows 10 without the Boot Camp Assistant can be found [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/308743/how-to-install-windows-10-into-a-2011-imac-without-using-the-boot-camp-assistant).

I should point out that [Microsoft support](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/end-of-support) ended for Windows 7 on January 4, 2010 and will end for Windows 8.1 on January 10, 2023.

According to the `info.plist` file included with the High Sierra version of the Boot Camp Assistant, your Mac (`MacBookPro8,1`) should require the use of DVD when using the Boot Camp Assistant to install Windows. I can not explain why the OP's question states the Boot Camp Assistant is asking for a flash drive, unless modifications have be made to the Boot Camp Assistant application.

According to [this Apple website](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201468), the only newest Intel Mac models can install Windows without a DVD or flash drive and the only version is 64 bit Windows 10. Your Mac is not one of these models. While your model Mac is probably capable of installing Windows without the use of a DVD or flash drive, I am unaware any website where such instructions are posted.

Your Mac does not meet [the minimum system requirements for Windows 11](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-11-specifications). However, [Microsoft](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/ways-to-install-windows-11-e0edbbfb-cfc5-4011-868b-2ce77ac7c70e) does leave the possibility of installing Windows 11 by use of the `dism` command. I used the `dism` command to do a clean install of Windows 11 on my iMac (21.5-inch, Mid 2011).

> Note: You can download, install and try Windows 10 or 11 without having a product key. However, to activate Windows you may need to purchase a product key. In the past, Microsoft has allowed free upgrades from Windows 7, 8 and 8.1 to Windows 10. Also, in the past, Windows 10 would accept a Windows 7, 8 or 8.1 product key. I do not know if either of these currently hold true.  Currently, there exists the possibility to activate Windows 11 on a Mac for free if the same Mac has had an activated Windows 10 tied to your Microsoft account.