# Restoring clonezilla image of iMac 2011 dual boot installation missing bootcamp at boot menu

Tags: bootcamp, imac

To successfully install High Sierra and Windows 10 Pro to my old iMac 2011, I used this guide:

[How to install Windows 10 into a 2011 iMac without using the Boot Camp Assistant, an optical (DVD) drive or third party tools?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/308743/how-to-install-windows-10-into-a-2011-imac-without-using-the-boot-camp-assistant)

Everything went great and worked great. Then problem is that the Clonezilla image I took and used to restore does not work for the Windows installation. Boot Camp exists, but is not shown in the boot menu. When booting from the Windows USB installation drive, the `diskpart` command shows a `*` under `GPT`, thus I cannot set Boot Camp partition as "active" and install MBR. High Sierra loads just fine.

Why Clonezilla image is not restoring EXACTLY the installation I had. How can I re-activate the Boot Camp partition after the image is restored (without having to go through the enabling of hybrid-GPT and installing Windows from scratch)?

Comment: You need to reinstall the Windows boot software. While installing Windows from scratch many not be necessary, converting from a full protected GPT to a hybrid-GPT should be done before reinstalling the Windows boot software. The software needed to reinstall the Windows boot software is on the Windows USB installation drive. One of the easiest methods of convert to a hybrid-GPT is to use "GPT fdisk". You can download [gdisk-windows-1.0.9.zip](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gptfdisk/files/gptfdisk/1.0.9/gdisk-binaries/) and add `gdisk64.exe` to the Windows USB installation drive.

Comment: Hi David and thank you for your answer! I discovered that after restoring the image I must follow these steps: 1) csrutil disable, 2) run sudo gdisk and the commands from the instructions, 3) reboot using Win10 USB, 4) shift+F10 and then diskpart->volume->active and finally bootsect /nt60 C: /mbr ...then windows 10 partition is working. The question remains.. why cant Clonezilla help avoid all this and just create an image of the hybrid-GPT system? Is there another cloning software that is able to do this? Thank you!!!